# Startup Scripts location override through Environment Variable?

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to modify the value of the temporary directory in the user preferences on startup. I have tried setting `$TMP` and `$TMPDIR` variables but they seem to be ignored even when I delete my user preferences in full or just emptying the Temp Dir field.

I'm now looking at having a startup script to set this variable with the value I need. I cannot however dump my python script in the scripts/startup folder.

Is there a way (via environment variable perhaps) to tell blender to look for startups scripts in another location? Or extend that lookup path?

Alternatively, do you have any suggestions on how to set

```
bpy.context.user_preferences.filepaths.temporary_directory = "/var/tmp"
```

without a startup script?

Many Thanks
GB

Comment: based on your description I would create a shortcut/link to the blender executable that loads your startup script. Then just call that rather than blender directly.